# How to maintain a copy of a table in memory in Azure SQL?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-sql-database, row-level-security

I am new to Azure and I need help.

We have a table USERS in Azure SQL on disk. This table is populated by admin team and we use the table data. This table is used for implementation of Row Level Security(RLS). We now want to create a new memory-optimized table and implement RLS on that table. For implementing RLS on memory-optimized the table USERS should also be memory optimized.
But we cannot move the USERS table to in memory as it will break RLS in other tables.
The admin team will not create another memory-optimized USERS table for us.

What is the best way to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

First thing would be to find out why the admin team do not want to create another USER table. I suspect that they are worried about the contents of each table diverging.

You need a USER table both on disk and in Memory.

One way to do this would be to sync from the table on disk to the table in memory, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/replication-to-memory-optimized-table-subscribers?view=sql-server-ver15

You would then never update the table in memory directly, and the contents of the tables would remain in sync.